# Why the following code doesn't print anything ..?

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

Why doesn't the following code doesn't output anything?

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = -1; i <= (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])); i++)
        printf("%d\n", array[i+1]); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Trying to be clever? `sizeof` is unsigned, hence the comparison `i < sizeof(...)` will compare a huge unsigned number (namely -1 as unsigned) with a small number, which is false. You should have gotten a warning.

Comment: You're lucky the loop doesn't run the way you would like it to, because then you would have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as the index would have gone out of bounds of the array.

Comment: but when i put 5 in place of "(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))" in loop it prints the array..

Comment: yes it printed 1 2 3 4 5 6

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the array index properly. With your current code, you'll be overrunning the array bound, producing [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Remember, array index in `c` is `0` based, meaning an array defined as `arr[n]` will have valid index from `arr[0]` to `arr[n-1]`.

That said, please keep in mind, `sizeof` operator returns a `size_t` which is usually `unsigned` type. So, the comparison of `signed` and `unsigned` will produce weird behavior.

Change your code to

```
int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
printf("%d\n", array[i]);
```